# ¿Cómo muestro un registro que se repite varias veces y que solo me aparezca ese registro?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
select ISBN_Libro, Titulo_Libro, Paginas_Libro, Anio_Libro, Precio_Libro, Nombre_Editorial, count(*) as Popularidad from libro
join editorial on libro.id_Editorial = editorial.id_Editorial
group by Nombre_Editorial
order by Pupularidad desc;
```

Estoy intentando mostrar el isbn, titulo, paginas, año y precio del libro, del nombre del editorial más popular (es decir
el editorial que más se repite o el que más libros tiene publicados) pero estoy teniendo problemas. Solo quiero que se me muestre los editoriales que más se repiten el resto no, como haria, tengo esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner un `LIMIT` que te muestre la cantidad de fila que quieras, por ejemplo, si quieres solo `5` agregas  `LIMIT 5` al final de la consulta.

Comment: ¿No hay otra manera, que solo me muestre los máximos sin usar el limit? Por ejemplo si únicamente 3 editoriales tienen igualdad de popularidad que el código únicamente me muestre esas tres, pero si se agrega un cuarto dato, que automáticamente muestre ese dato y si ese dato agregado supera a los tres datos anteriores que solo muestre ese dato superior y los otrs tres no. No hay alguna forma?

Comment: Nada es imposible, sin embargo, debes exponer con claridad el problema, poniendo si es posible un pequeño set de datos, la consulta que estás intentando, lo que obtienes y lo que esperas obtener. Evita las capturas de pantalla, [si puedes crear un fiddle y compartirlo mucho mejor](https://www.db-fiddle.com/). Una captura de pantalla no sirve de nada para este caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ISBN_Libro , Titulo_libro , Paginas_Libro ,Anio_Libro ,Precio_Libro , 
Nombre_Editorial from libro l
INNER JOIN editorial e ON l.id_Editorial=e.id_Editorial
where e.id_Editorial = (
select id_Editorial from ( select e.id_Editorial, Nombre_Editorial,
count(*) as c from libro l
INNER JOIN editorial e ON l.id_Editorial=e.id_Editorial
group by Nombre_Editorial
order by c desc
limit 1) as nueva_tabla
)
```

Dando y dando, ya con este codigo me funciono usando un inner join y buscando dentro de filas mientras uso unas condicionales.